# Will single docker container scale automatically on Amazon's EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, containers

I created a single Docker container on Amazon's EC2 default instance. 
I am wondering will my app automatically scale if there is a sudden spike in traffic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not much is setup *automatically* in AWS.  In very broadly outlined strokes, to achieve your goal, you'd need to roll the following:

- An elastic load balancer
- A launch config based on the image of the EC2 instance you want to scale.
- An autoscaling group set to add another instance based on load

This is way outside the scope of what can be answered quickly in a SO post.

Judging by the question however, I'd recommend learning about ElasticBeanstalk (EB).  You can setup a docker enabled beanstalk. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker.html

EB takes handles configuring the above for you--all you need to do is specify min an max instances you want to scale to.